# what do I need to do so that when dragging in only one file is displayed and only show file name

Tags: java, javafx

I want to change the style of the file to get in the list to only display the file name, but I tried many ways, when I change  to , the file name will fill the entire listview after dragging in the file but When I want to use  it says: "Error return type in lambda expression: ListCell cannot be cast to ListCell", what do I need to do so that when dragging in only one file is displayed and only show file name

```
inputListView.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        boolean success = false;
        if (db.hasFiles()) {
            success = true;
            String filePath;


            int total_files = db.getFiles().size();
            for (int i = 0; i < total_files; i++) {

                    File file = db.getFiles().get(i);
                    filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();


                    inputListView.getItems().add(filePath);
                int input_files = db.getFiles().size();
                for (int x = 0; x < input_files; x++) {
                    File file2 = db.getFiles().get(x);
                    String filename;
                    filename = file2.getName();
                    inputListView.setCellFactory(inputListView -> new ListCell<String>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(String filename, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(filename, empty);

                            setText(file2.getName());
                        }
                    });
                }

            }



        }
        event.setDropCompleted(success);
        event.consume();
    });
```

Comment: See if the following can help. https://github.com/sedj601/FileExplorer/blob/master/src/fileexplorer/FXMLDocumentController.java

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the cell factory at all inside a user-initiated event such as a drag drop.  If you want to change the data in the list, modify the items list which backs the list, not the cell factories.  You only want to display a text file name it seems, so unless the list of type <File> then you don't need a cell factory to render the file name. Put the relevant file names in the list at the appropriate location.

Comment: What would be the behavior if the user did drag multiple files into the ListView, shouldn't you add them all?  And where do you want the new files added in the list? Inserted at the location they are dragged to?  Or appended to the end of the list?  Or is order in the list immaterial for your purposes?